# Positioning layers

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

At the moment I'm working on a quite comprehensive (well at least for me) imagemagic task. I want to add some annotations i extract from exif-data and adding an overlay image.
At the moment i'm having the following code:

```
convert -verbose source.jpg \
    -pointsize 32 -fill white -undercolor '#00000070' -gravity NorthWest -annotate +10+10 "some exif data"\
    -pointsize 32 -fill white -undercolor '#00000070' -gravity North     -annotate +10+10 "more exif data"\
    -pointsize 32 -fill white -undercolor '#00000070' -gravity NorthEast -annotate +10+10 "even more exif data"\
    -gravity South overlay.png \
    -layers flatten \
    -quality 95 destination.jpg;
```

The annotation works fine including the position. But i stuck with the overlay. It seems the the "-gravity South" doesn't work here. It stuck on the upper left corner. What do i have to change to get the overlay to the bottom and centered?

Bonus question: How to get the overlay semitransparent?

Comment: Post your original images and results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `-composite` rather than `-flatten` with your `convert`:

```
convert -verbose source.jpg \
    -pointsize 32 -fill white -undercolor '#00000070' -gravity NorthWest -annotate +10+10 "some exif data"\
    -pointsize 32 -fill white -undercolor '#00000070' -gravity North     -annotate +10+10 "more exif data"\
    -pointsize 32 -fill white -undercolor '#00000070' -gravity NorthEast -annotate +10+10 "even more exif data"\
    -gravity South overlay.png -composite \
    result.jpg
```

[image]

If you want the overlay semi-transparent, use:

```
convert -verbose source.jpg \
    -pointsize 32 -fill white -undercolor '#00000070' -gravity NorthWest -annotate +10+10 "some exif data"\
    -pointsize 32 -fill white -undercolor '#00000070' -gravity North     -annotate +10+10 "more exif data"\
    -pointsize 32 -fill white -undercolor '#00000070' -gravity NorthEast -annotate +10+10 "even more exif data"\
    \( -gravity South overlay.png -channel A -fx "0.5" \) -composite \
    result.jpg
```

---

By the way, `-pointsize`, `-fill`, and `-undercolor` are *"settings"*, so they remain set until changed, so you don't need to repeat them:

```
convert -verbose source.jpg -pointsize 32 -fill white -undercolor '#00000070' \
    -gravity NorthWest -annotate +10+10 "some exif data"\
    -gravity North     -annotate +10+10 "more exif data"\
    -gravity NorthEast -annotate +10+10 "even more exif data"\
    \( -gravity South overlay.png -channel A -fx "0.5" \) -composite \
    result.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add overlay with `composite` not `convert`.

```
convert -verbose source.jpg \
    -pointsize 32 -fill white -undercolor '#00000070' -gravity NorthWest -annotate +10+10 "some exif data"\
    -pointsize 32 -fill white -undercolor '#00000070' -gravity North     -annotate +10+10 "more exif data"\
    -pointsize 32 -fill white -undercolor '#00000070' -gravity NorthEast -annotate +10+10 "even more exif data"\
    -layers flatten \
    -quality 95 destination.jpg;
```

and then:

```
composite -gravity South overlay.png destination.jpg result.jpg
```

More on `composite` [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/composite.php).

**Edit:** Best way would be to use ImageMagick intermediate save format `miff` and pipelining. This will save extra steps of read/write from disk.

```
convert -verbose source.jpg \
        -pointsize 32 -fill white -undercolor '#00000070' -gravity NorthWest -annotate +10+10 "some exif data"\
        -pointsize 32 -fill white -undercolor '#00000070' -gravity North     -annotate +10+10 "more exif data"\
        -pointsize 32 -fill white -undercolor '#00000070' -gravity NorthEast -annotate +10+10 "even more exif data"\
        -layers flatten \
        -quality 95 miff:- | \

composite -gravity South overlay.png miff:- destination.jpg
```